# Strong approximation theorem for Dedekind Domains

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

This is a theorem in "Maximal Orders" by Reiner. Page 48 stated without proof. And is said to be an easy consequence of The Chinese remainder Theorem. I am attempting to prove the theorem and need a little help.

R is a Dedekind domain with fraction field $K$.

> Let $P_{1},\cdots ,P_{n}$ be distinct non zero prime ideals of the Dedekind Domain $R$, and let $a_{1},\cdots ,a_{n}\in K$ be given as well as positive integers $r_{1},\cdots,r_{n}$. Then there exists $b\in K$ such that 
>   $$\begin{cases}b-a_{i}\in(P_{i})^{r_{i}}\cdot R_{P_{i}}& 1\leq i\leq n,\\ b\in R_{P}&\text{for all } P\neq P_{1},\cdots,P_{n}, \end{cases}$$
>   Where $P$ denotes a variable nonzero prime ideal of $R$.

My attempt is as follows.

First assume that each $a_{i}\in R$. Then by chinese remainder theorem there exists $b\in R$ such that $b\equiv a_{i}\mod P_{i}^{r_{i}}$ for all $i$. Therefore $b-a_{i}\in P_{i}^{r_{i}}\subset P_{i}^{r_{i}}\cdot R_{P_{i}}$. Also since $b\in R$, $b\in R_{P}$ for all $P$ prime. Now let $a_{i}\in K$. Then for each $i$, $a_{i}=x_{i}/s_{i}$ for $x_{i},s_{i}\in R$ and $s_{i}\neq 0$. Define $a'_{i}=a_{i}\prod_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}$. Then each $a'_{i}\in R$. There exists $b\in R$ such that $b\equiv a'_{i}\mod P_{i}^{r_{i}}$ for each $i$. I claim that $b'=\tfrac{b}{\prod s_{i}}$ is the element that does the above.

The issue that I am running into is I have no controll over the $s_{i}$. Therefore I have no way to ensure that $b'-a_{i}=(b-a'_{i})/\prod s_{i}$ is in $P_{i}^{r_{i}}\cdot R_{P_{i}}$. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite to reflect the context of the text the op is using:**

Let's prove we can do it for one, then using the CRT we will bootstrap to the others.

Then if we want to match some $b_i$ with the right property relative to $P_i$, and then it's easy to make sure $b_i\in R_P$ for $P\ne P_i$ because it won't change the $P_i$ valuation of $b_i$.

But then this is just a matter of choosing a $b_i\in K$ as any element from $a_i+P_i^{r_i}$, then by definition $b_i$ has the requisite property, and you can reconstruct $b$ from the $b_i$ as you do when you piece together CRT things. The existence of the appropriate multipliers follows from weak-approximation (not a small part of the proof, despite brevity).

Comment: Well how do I know that all of the $a_{i}$ are in fact in $S^{-1}R$ to begin with. I need that fact to use CRT. That is my sticking point.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Can you provide context as to what else you already know/has been done in this text's development? I'm trying to think of an easy way to phrase this, but anything that just involves pure algebra seems too complicated to be "an easy consequence of the CRT," as the author claims; strong approximation is a pretty big generalization and goes through weak approximation in the middle.

Comment: In this section the author covered, factorization of ideals in Dedekind domains and fractional ideals. Then GCD and LCM of ideals. That was it.

Comment: @TheNumber23 I don't know exactly what the author means by "easy consequence" in that case, it requires more stuff than that to prove strong approximation, but I've edited my original post a little to give the idea. Strong approximation uses weak approximation (at least all forms I've seen it in). Other than that, constructing the pieces isn't terrible, you look at fractional cosets, i.e. translates of your ideal by the appropriate $a_i\in K$ then stitch them together just like the CRT.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Let $S$ be the finite set of prime ideals that divide $s = \prod s_i$. For a prime ideal $P$, denote $e(P)$ the exponent of $P$ in the prime factorization of $s$. Then use the CRT to find $b \in R$ with $b \equiv a_i' \pmod {P_i^{r_i + e(P_i)}}$ for all $i$, and $b \equiv 0 \pmod {P^{e(P)}}$ for all $P \in S$. Then $b' = b/s$ does the job.